# Clear only JavaScript console.info and not the entire log

Tags: javascript

I have an application that has a container refresh every X number of seconds.

Everything is in the proper syntax without creating any errors but instead logs the "`XHR finished loading: POST ...`" within the log info repeatedly when someone stays on the page.

How do I clear just the `console.info` output without clearing the entire log?

I do not want to use `console.clear()` as it clears everything unless someone opts to conserve the log.

What I need is to just clear the `console.info()` ... Thus far I am not able to find the answer to this.

To clarify: I would like an actual JavaScript command to do this automatically. I am not seeking any manual browser setting. This needs to be an actual JavaScript command or function. No jQuery either, please, just raw JavaScript.

Thanks.

Comment: It's a browser setting that you can't change from code.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply change the levels on console to not show info

[image]

Comment: I need a javascript command to do it and not via a browser setting.

Comment: I don't know any such command, and as far as i know there isn't any such